# Bash history command, store whole term ignoring any options

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script which repeatedly waits for user entered text and then calls another script with the entered text. [SO code credit, 'version 1'.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6794304/2102457)

```bash
while IFS="" read -r -e -p 'Enter search term: ' -a search_term; do

    if [ "$search_term" != "" ]; then
        /path/to/script ${search_term[@]}

    else
        echo "Bye."
        exit 0
    fi

    history -s ${search_term[@]}

done
```

It calls the Bash builtin `history` command to allow scrolling up to previous entries.

The problem is when `search_term` begins with an option, e.g. `-x exclude_this search term`. This results in the following error: `history: -x: invalid option`. How do I force the `history` command to add the whole of `search_term` as a history entry and not to process any options that `search_term` may begin with? i.e. The whole of `-x exclude_this search term` should be added as a history entry.

Note: This can actually be solved by adding an initial empty string like this `history -s "" ${search_term[@]}` but each history entry is then prefixed by a space and repeated use adds a space each time pushing the entries further and further right. So this is a rather inelegant solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself in a question on [SE Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/79040).

By using a double dash (`--`) in the `history` command you can stop a Bash built-in command from processing what follows as options. So all that I needed to change was this:

```bash
history -s -- ${search_term[@]}
```